# Simple form: set current_user.username as value for commenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to set the name of the current user as the value for the commenter.

when i use: `<%= f.input :commenter, :input_html => { :value => '<% current_user.username %>' }, label: false, disabled: true %>` I get a syntax error.

Actually, I don't want to display the commentor on adding the comment; only on the listing.

Besides Simple_form, I use Devise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're openning the ERB tag twice in the same expression, hence the syntax error. Try :

```
<%= f.input :commenter, :input_html => { :value => current_user.username }, label: false, disabled: true %>
```

Comment: how dumb can I be :-)